# create text file in /tmp folder in Linux using c language

Tags: c, linux

By using c language I need to create a text file in `/tmp` directory, but I don't know how to do this. Is there anyone who knows how to create a text file in `/tmp` folder?

Comment: google about file IOs

Comment: I know how to create a folder in current directory but I want to create linux /tmp folder

Comment: You know how to create a directory. but you don't know how to create a text file?

Comment: what speciality in `/tmp` folder?? you can create a text file in any folder.

Comment: that is how the assignment.

Comment: I asked prof. to create /tmp folder but he told me there is a /tmp directory in linux, I need to use it not create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("/tmp/myfile.txt","w");
    if (pFile!=NULL)
    {
          //write
         fclose (pFile);
     }
     return 0;
   }
```

If /tmp/myfile.txt isn't there one will be created.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that some other program might be working with the specified file, i.e. `"/tmp/thefile.txt"`. It could be another instance of the same program too. Safer is to use `mkstemp()`.

Comment: finally you did his assignment. you made him lazy.

Comment: @SCG. I understand The reason that I gave the code from the link is to emphasize to the OP the answers are out there. Just a thoughtful search is needed. Hopefully OP realises that.

Comment: @Arun, Thanks for the pointing that out. Was not aware of `mkstemp()` till now. Let me try that out.

Answer (score 1):

There's  [`mkstemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp) function for this

Comment: I don't want to create a new tmp folder, I want to use linux /tmp folder

Comment: `mkstemp()` doesn't create a new folder.

Comment: You don't create a temporary folder with this function. You simply create a file in a folder configured to contain temporary files, and the file is guaranteed not to interfer with other temporary files even being simultaneously created. That's why 'd suggest to use the function instead of the manual method

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>  // Defines fopen(), fclose(), fprintf(), printf(), etc.
#include <errno.h>  // Defines errno
```

C programs generally start with the 'main()' function.

```
int main()
   {
   int rCode=0;
   FILE *fp = NULL;
```

'fp' will be a reference to the file, used to read, write, or close the file.

```
   char *filePath = "/tmp/thefile.txt";
```

'filePath' is a string that holds the path "/tmp" and the filename "thefile.txt".

The following line attempts to open the file in "write" mode, which (if successful) will cause the file "thefile.txt" to be created in the "/tmp" directory.

```
   fp=fopen(filePath, "w");
```

Incidently, with the "w" (write) mode specified, it "thefile.txt" already exists in the "/tmp" directory, it will be overwritten.

The following code will print an error if the file could not be created.

```
   if(NULL==fp)
      {
      rCode=errno;
      fprintf(stderr, "fopen() failed.  errno[%d]\n", errno);
      }
```

After the file is created, it could be written to here:

```
   fprintf(fp, "This is the content of the text file.\nHave a nice day!\n");
```

Now, the file can be closed.

```
   if(fp)
      fclose(fp);
```

All done.

```
   return(rCode);
   }
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that some other program might be working with the specified file, i.e. `"/tmp/thefile.txt"`. It could be another instance of the same program too. Safer is to use `mkstemp()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
char *tmp_file;
char buf[1000];
FILE *fp;

tmp_file = "/tmp/sometext.txt";

fp = fopen( tmp_file, "w" );

if ( fp == NULL ) {
  printf("File open error! %s", tmp_file );
}

sprintf( buf, "Hello" );

fputs( buf, fp );
fclose( fp );
```

Answer (score 0):

Several other people have mentioned that the correct way to do this is to use the [mkstemp()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html) function, that is because it will ensure your file has a unique name.

Here is a quick example of how to use it:

```
//Set file name    
char filename[] = "/tmp/tmpfile-XXXXXX";

//Open the file in rw mode, X's replaced with random chars
int fd = mkstemp(filename);

//Write stuff to file...
write(fd, filename, strlen(filename));

//Close the file
close(fd);

//Do whatever else you want here, including opening and closing the file again

//Once you are done delete the temporary file
unlink(filename);
```

I left out error checking on purpose for clarity.